# Higher order ODE's - factoring using the derivative operator $D$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, operator-theory

I am dealing a little hastily with some texts on ODE's and did not understand the following. A professor had a 3ª order ODE and suggest factorate at form:

$$(D^2+p_1(x)D+p_2(x))(D+p_3(x))y(x)=0,$$ where $D=d/dx$.

He said that $(D+p_3(x))\overline{y}(x)=0$ for a solution $\overline{y}$. I ask why?

I could not understand...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess what he meant was that if $(D+P_3(x))\overline{y}(x)=0$ then $\overline{y}(x)$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe yes..